# How can I move aircraft to other continents?

Tags: civilization-5

In *Civilization 5*, I have built multiple aircrafts such as Bombers, Zeros, and Paratroopers. I move my planes to my city closest to my enemy (on a different continent), but my planes cannot make an air strike on the enemy, because it is so far away.

Is it possible to move aircraft overseas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either do one of two things:

1. Establish a beachhead by conquering one of his cities and use it as a base to begin bombing others.
2. Research and build an [aircraft carrier](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Carrier_(Civ5)) and use it as a mobile base (of doom) to launch air strikes.